# how to add data attribute to a <li> element in wordpress nav menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-data-attribute, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js on a wordpress site and would like to use one of it's function wicht is to add a class on a li. But to do this you need to add the data attribute data-menuanchor .

I have seen this:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_attribs', 10, 3 );
function my_nav_menu_attribs( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // The ID of the target menu item
  $menu_target = 113;

  // inspect $item
  if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
    $atts['data-menuanchor'] = 's1';

  }
  return $atts;
}
```

It works excepts that it adds the attribute to the a tag and need it to be on the li tag.

Also, if I want to do it to all the items on the menu. Do I need to do this function for all the items? And I suppose I have to rename the function each time?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure WP has a specific filter/method for this.  You're gonna have to do some manual DOM manipulation along with `wp_nav_menu_items`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/

```
function addDataAttr( $items, $args ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($items);
    $find = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

    foreach ($find as $item ) :
        $item->setAttribute('data-menuanchor','s1');
    endforeach;

    return $dom->saveHTML();

}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'addDataAttr', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Instead of using s1, how would I grab the name of the item itself? So if the menu item was "home" for example, how would I grab "home"?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this, using the custom links and getting the url entered in the link as an attribute and replacing the # character with empty. The following code must be entered in the file functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_data_atts_to_nav', 10, 4 );
    function add_data_atts_to_nav( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['data-menuanchor'] = strtolower(str_replace("#","",$item->url));
    return $atts;
}
```

Attached screenshot of my menu.

Any questions tell me and I gladly help them.

Luck.

[image]

Comment: This worked great thanks. For me also req'd adding the parent ul id to the fullpage.js.min initialize options for the "menu" attribute, which for me was: menu: '#menu-top-menu'

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress 6.3.0 there is a new filter: [nav_menu_item_attributes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_item_attributes/) that you can use to add attributes to nav menu `<li>` elements, like this:

```
function my_custom_nav_menu_item_attributes( $li_atts, $menu_item, $args, $depth ) {
    $li_atts['data-menuanchor'] = 's1';
    return $li_atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_attributes', 'my_custom_nav_menu_item_attributes', 10, 4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was searching for a similar thing for fullpage.js navigation,i managed it setting up a filter that get the pre-existing title-attr customizable from backend and assign it to 'data-menuanchor' just to keep it at least a minimum scalable and mantainable even if i have to add something new.

Here's what i've used.

```
function add_specific_menu_atts( $atts, $item, $args ) {

  $atts['data-menuanchor'] = $item->attr_title;


return $atts;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_specific_menu_atts', 10, 3 );
```