# how to add data attribute to a specific <li> element in wordpress nav menu

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-data-attribute

I'm using wordpress and trying to add a data-attribute to just 1 main menu item. Specifically to a < li> element. I saw this link ([how to add data attribute to a <li> element in wordpress nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579220/how-to-add-data-attribute-to-a-li-element-in-wordpress-nav-menu)) and I'm trying to narrow it down as it currently (and obviously targets every < li> item).

Here is my code that works just fine, as the correct behaviour is only triggered when the plugins' associated class is also present (which is only in that 1 item). But I want to learn the more targeted approach.

```
function booking_menu_atts( $items, $args ) {
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($items);
$find = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

foreach ($find as $item ) :
    $item->setAttribute('data-agent','any');
    $item->setAttribute('data-hide-panel','yes');
endforeach;
return $dom->saveHTML();}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'booking_menu_atts', 10, 3);
```

This works, but how do I target a < li> menu item with either a specific class or a specific < li> menu id

Not sure if the language I've used it clear enough, but I want to improve, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add specific behavior to some menu or submenu li.

This can be easily achieved by going to

> WP backend -> menus -> click on an item and below label you will have CSS Classes (optional) - here you can add class and write its respective css.

To have this, go to screen options and enable css classes - Refer to attached images

[image]

[image]

Another option [how to add data attribute to a <li> element in wordpress nav menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579220/how-to-add-data-attribute-to-a-li-element-in-wordpress-nav-menu?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your "li" some ID and instead of:

```php
$find = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');
```

Try:

```php
$find = $dom->getElementsById('#youridname');
```

Comment: I tried researching how to add #ID tags to menu items in wordpress and that seems like a whole other set of tasks, I tried researching classes too and it seems getElementsByClassName() is a thing but I couldn't get it to work without a critical error. So this did not work for me as I can't use the #Id tag or don't know how to.